# How do i suppress mouse wheel event of container control?

Tags: c#, .net, events, mouse

I have a **silverlight page** with **scroll viewer** in it.

**Inside scorll viewer I have a user control.** (user control is **like a NumericUpDown** control.)

*I have implemented Mouse-wheel event of Text-box inside User control.*

**When I scroll mouse wheel on User controls user controls Mouse-wheel event gets fire** but at  **same time my scrollviewer also moves up and down.**

How do I suppress scroll viewer mouse wheel event when focus is on the user control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In user control code register `PreviewMouseWheel` event and set `e.Handled` to true. This will stop the event propagation.